# Python вывод текста, игнорируя регистр и заданные знаки

Tags: python, python-3.x

В книге "Укус Питона" есть задание:
Проверка, является ли текст палиндромом должна также игнорировать знаки пунктуации, пробелы и регистр букв. Например, «А роза упала на лапу Азора» также является палиндромом, но наша текущая программа так не считает. Попробуйте улучить её так, чтобы она распознала этот палиндром.

Вот код который распознает отдельные слова:

```
def reverse(text):
    return text[::-1]

def  palindrome(text):
    return text == reverse(text)

something = input('Введите текст: ')

forbidden=('.','?','!',':',';','-','—',' ',)

if (palindrome(something)):
    print('Yes this palindrome')
else:
    print('this is not a palindrome')'
```

я написал кортеж с символами которые нужно исключить `forbidden=('.','?','!',':',';','-','—',' ',)`
Но как сделать проверку этих символов с последующим их удалением из текста - не понимаю. Просмотрел еще раз предыдущие главы, ничего об этом не нашел. В сети есть решения, но они используют модуль `re`, а так-как в книге о нем ничего не говорилось, я предполагаю, что есть другое решение, более очевидное. Подскажите, пожалуйста,что я упустил.

Comment: `for symbol in forbidden: if symbol in something: something = something.replace(symbol, "")`

Comment: Способ, который оставит в тексте **только** буквы и цифры: `"".join(symbol for symbol in something if symbol.isalnum())`

Comment: Чтобы игнорировать регистры, можете всю строку перевести в нижний/верхний регистр: `something.lower()`, `something.upper()`

Comment: а проверку регистра в этот цикл можно воткнуть?

Comment: Вам необходимо не различать регистр у букв? Или убирать символы верхнего/нижнего регистра?

Comment: не различать,я уже поправил,все получилось как надо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение:

```
# Для игнорирования регистра строка переводится в один регистр
# Например, нижний
something = something.lower()

# Если Вам необходимо удалить только символы, которые есть в forbidden
something = "".join(symbol for symbol in something if symbol not in forbidden)

# Если Вам необходимо оставить в тексте только буквы и цифры
something = "".join(symbol for symbol in something if symbol.isalnum())
```

Answer (score 1):

Первым делом отфильтровать все знаки пунктуации и пробелы, а затем сравнить с перевёрнутой строкой в одном регистре:

```
>>> def isPalindrome(text):
...     text = ''.join(filter(str.isalnum, text))
...     return text.upper() == text[::-1].upper()
...
>>> isPalindrome('Ab9,cc 9 Ba')
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже читал укус питона совсем недавно, я решил эту задачу не так элегантно как остальные. Но все таки решил используя знания которые получил из предыдущих глав.

```
def reverse(text):
    return text[::-1]

def palindrome(text): 
    return text == reverse(text)

something = input('Please Enter the text: ')

something = something.lower()

forbidden = (',', '.', '!', '?', ';', ':', '-')

for i in something:
    if i in forbidden:
        something = something.replace(i, '')
if (palindrome(something)):
    print('polindrom')
else:
    print('not a polindrom')
```

Comment: в `def reverse(text):` нет return'а

Comment: Вы не сохраняете строку, которую возвращает `something.lower()`, для удаления спец. символов лучше пробегать по запрещенным символам, и если они есть в тексте, то заменять их на `""`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def reverse(text):
    return text[::-1]
def is_palindrome(text):
    return text == reverse(text)
something = input('Введите текст: ')
something = ''.join([c for c in something if c not in ('!', '?')])#и другие 
#знаки препинания вставляй
something = something.replace(" ", "")
something = something.lower()
print(something)#это не обязательно 
if (is_palindrome(something)):
    print("Да, это палиндром")
else:
    print("Нет, это не палиндром")
```

у меня вот так вышло

Answer (score 0):

```
def reverse(text):
    return '' .join(text[::-1].lower().split())
def isPalindrome(text):
    return ''.join(text.lower().split())  == reverse(text)
tt = 'У кур лису кум обуздал в силу лис в лад зубом укусил руку'
if (isPalindrome(tt)):
    print('Yes, its palindrome')
else:
    print('Not, its not palindrome ')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю еще один метод, как можно избавиться от ненужных символов в строке:

```
def isPalindrome(text):
    return text.lower() == text.translate(str.maketrans('','','.,:;-?! ')).lower()[::-1]
```