# Пожалуйста, скажите из-за чего код работает не так

Tags: python-3.x

```py
def clear(text):
    clearchar= ".",",",";","[]","/","?","-","...","!","—","’","()",'""'
    for prot in clearchar:
        global hh

        hh = text.replace(prot,"")
        text = hh
        print(hh)
    return hh

def reverse(text):
    global hh
    clear(text)
    print(hh,hh)

    hh= hh[::-1]
    print(hh)
    print(hh[::-1])

def is_palindrome(text):
    reverse(text)
    print(hh)
    hh[::-1]==hh

something=input('Введите текст:') 
if(is_palindrome(something)):
    print("Да, это палиндром") 
else:
    print("Нет, это не палиндром")
```

оригинал для доработки из byte of python

```py
def reverse(text):
   return text[::-1]

def is_palindrome(text):
   return text==reverse(text)

something=input('Введите текст:')
if(is_palindrome(something)):
   print("Да, это палиндром")
else:
   print("Нет, это не палиндром")
```

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что он работает не так?

Comment: я каждый раз получаю ответ о том что слово или предложение не палиндром

Comment: Что делает (должно делать) if и что оно получает от is_palindrome?

Comment: hh[::-1]==hh должно выдавать true или false

Comment: Куда? Почитайте еще раз про возврат значений из функций. А потом разберитесь в какой переменной что находится, у вас какое-то месиво в коде. Что сохранено в hh?

Comment: У вас в коде столько ошибок, что вам определённо стоит перечитать учебники по python

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/959142/python-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в коде логическая ошибка

1. Вы не возвращали значения из функций (return), из-за чего возвращался None
2. У вас много мусора в коде
3. Неверная логика в вашем reverse. Вы сначала реверсите, а потом сравниваете с реверсом от реверса

Вот мое предложение решения вопроса

```
def clear(text):
    clearchar= ".",",",";","[]","/","?","-","...","!","—","’","()",'""'
    for prot in clearchar:
        # Мы можем присвоить той же переменной новое значение
        text = text.replace(prot, "") 
    # Не забываем возвращать результат функции
    return text

def reverse(text):
    text = clear(text)
    # Не забываем возвращать результат функции
    return text[::-1]

def is_palindrome(text):
    # B снова не забываем возвращать результат функции
    return text == reverse(text)

something=input('Введите текст:') 
if(is_palindrome(something)):
    print("Да, это палиндром") 
else:
    print("Нет, это не палиндром")
```